# python -m <filename> <encoding>?

Tags: python, python-2.7, non-ascii-characters

**How to specify encoding when running python script as a module?**

For example, I want to run `my_script.py` as `python -m my_script -utf8`. But there is no such an option. Instead, I should provide `my_script.py` with encoding on top of the file. And it fails with some python-2.7 packages.

Consider next scenario:

> my_script.py:

```
# coding=utf-8
from pyglet.gl import *
```

1. `$ cd ~/Documents`
2. create non-ascii folder: `$ mkdir вафля`
3. `$ cd вафля`
4. create `my_script.py` with the code above
5. `python my_script.py` -- works well
6. `python -m my_script` -- fails

Work station: Ubuntu 14.04.3 x64 + Python 2.7.6 x64 (built-in)

Do not suggest me to switch on Python 3.4 because I've already done it and just want to support both 2.7 and 3.4 versions of Python.

Added traceback.

```
File "my_script.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 236, in <module>
    import pyglet.window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1817, in <module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 205, in _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 163, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 559, in __init__
    self._create()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 353, in _create
    self.set_caption(self._caption)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 511, in set_caption
    self._set_text_property('WM_NAME', caption, allow_utf8=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 785, in _set_text_property
    buf = create_string_buffer(value.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you have any control over how arbitrary Python modules handle non-ASCII data...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, the string variable `value` on which the code crashes contains non-unicode path to `my_script.py`. If there was an attribute in `-m` option, I'd pass it to wrap `my_script.py`'s path in a unicode - if the was a way to add `u''` character before path value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `pyglet`. It using `sys.argv[0]` as its default window caption, but it expects the caption string to be a `unicode` instance, which it can later `encode` to ASCII (ignoring non-representable unicode values). However, in Python 2, `sys.argv[0]` will be a bytestring (a `str` instance) in some encoding (I'm not sure if the encoding specified anywhere or if it might vary from filesystem to filesystem). When you try to `encode` an already encoded bytestring, Python 2 first tries to decode the string to a `unicode` object using the `ascii` codec, before encoding as requested.

You're seeing this bug bite you only when you use the `-m` flag because only in that situation (of the ways you tested) is the non-ASCII part of the path included in `sys.argv[0]`. When you call `python my_script.py`, `sys.argv[0]` is `"my_script.py"`. When you use `-m`, `sys.argv[0]` will be the absolute path to the script file (including the non-ASCII folder).

I'm not sure exactly what a proper fix would be, since, as I mentioned above, I'm not sure the encoding used by `sys.argv` is well specified in Python 2. If you want to fix the issue just for your system, you can probably just change these lines in `pyglet/window/__init__.py` (they should be roughly lines 555-556):

```
        if caption is None:
            caption = sys.argv[0]
```

To:

```
        if caption is None:
            caption = sys.argv[0].decode("utf8")
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply. I won't modify package's scripts since I want my project to be able to run with fresh pip installs. Do you think it's worth creating an issue in pyglet community?

Comment: I already have, [here](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issues/74/pyglet-crashes-with-a-unicodeerror-on). I'd meant to link to that report here, but it seems I forgot didn't do so. Please add additional information if you have any you think is relevant!